# PHP: Simple XML has no xlink:href parsed

Tags: php, xml, xlink

I have a XML-File which I get from a curl response.
When I call the file in the browser it looks like this:

```
<result xsi:schemaLocation="http://mylink.com/xsd/1.0/item.xsd">
<item id="12345">
<name>Product X</name>
<images>
<image lastUpdate="2017-01-18T11:33:05+02:00">
<sizes>
<size maxwidth="74" width="74" height="59" filesize="2452" xlink:href="http://mylink.com/images/1008374"/>
<size maxwidth="320" width="320" height="256" filesize="34502" xlink:href="http://mylink.com/images/1008375"/>
<size maxwidth="800" width="750" height="600" filesize="175894" xlink:href="http://mylink.com/images/1008376"/>
</sizes>
</image>
</images>
</item>
</result>
```

But when I parse it with SimpleXmlElement it looks like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12345
                )

            [name] => Product X
        )
        [images] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [image] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [lastUpdate] => 2017-01-18T11:33:05+02:00
                                        )

                                    [sizes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [size] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [maxwidth] => 74
                                                                    [width] => 74
                                                                    [height] => 74
                                                                    [filesize] => 3476
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object.....
```

So there is no xlink:href attribute anymore in my images node. I read something about to add an Attribute but I don't no where, because the xlink element is cut when I generate my SimpleXML-Element.
Has anyone an idea how to get the xlink attribute?

Comment: The reason I believe is because of the Colon in the attribute. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858136/accessing-namespace-colon-nodes-in-xml-with-simplexml-php